# Symfony2: how to set the host/base url in CLI scripts

Tags: php, symfony, routes, command-line-interface

I'm currently writing a newsletter tool, and therefore have to generate absolute URLs in a CLI script which is called via cron.

Unfortunately the Symfony CLI command does not know anything about my host/base_url, so the router generates absolute URLs with a wrong base_url. It always uses `http://localhost` as base.

Is there a way to tell the router the correct base_url?

My code:

```
$this->container->get('router')->generate($route, $parameters, true);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
$host = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('host');
$this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext()->setHost($host);
```

Similarly you can set baseurl and scheme:

```
$this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext()->setScheme('https');
$this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext()->setBaseUrl('/web');
```

Comment: I also needed this functionality and as it is probably needed in many sites I've created a bundle:

http://packagist.org/packages/frosas/base-url-bundle

Comment: You can configure this globally in the ```parameters.yml```. It will only be taken for non-web requests so no need to worry about your "real" routes being affected by this. Reference: [Configuring the Request Context globally](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html#configuring-the-request-context-globally).

Answer (score 15):

Since 2.1 you can configure the default parameters of the router, which is probably the best approach. A CLI script will use these default parameters, however a web request will override them:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    router.request_context.host: example.org
    router.request_context.scheme: https
    router.request_context.base_url: my/path
```

For more details, see [How to Generate URLs and Send Emails from the Console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html)

Comment: This does not seem to work in Symfony 3 for me. Would you happen to know if it is supposed to work in SF3 please?

Comment: In fact this work in SF3 but it's not app/config/parameters.yml but app/config/services.yml

Answer (score 1):

`$host = $this->container->getParameter('host');
$this->container->get('router')->getContext()->setHost($host);`