# How to render asset URLs without a Request scope

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've come across a problem which is explained well in this GitHub issue
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4514

Short version: It's not possible to render asset URLs from the CLI because there is no Request object. The Github issue is closed. I suppose it is not a bug, but it is stopping my system from rendering HTML emails in cronjobs.

**So my question:**

Is there a way to allow templates to use `{{ asset() }}` from within a Symfony Command where there is no server request scope?

Some kind of dummy request sounds like it could work, but I have no idea how to get into that particular black box.

Comment: maybe a duplicate question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503250/symfony2-how-to-set-the-host-base-url-in-cli-scripts

Comment: useful thread thanks, but actually it doesn't address the specific problem of  using the asset helper when there's not request scope.

Comment: which version of sf2  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like explained in [how to send emails in console command](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html)

do like this

```
$context = $this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext();
$context->setHost('example.com');
$context->setScheme('https');
```

Comment: That's great thank. It fixes the URL generation issue,m but it does't fix the `{{asset}}` problem though. As the Github issue states. the assets helper doesn't work when there's no request scope.

Comment: exact... you have no choice that generating url from router or building your own url with custom parameters stored in your container, and use them in your template

Comment: this is unfortunate. I've worked around it using a simple base href  parameter in my templates. I may try later on to access `assets_version` manually so I can use my CDN. It'll do for now. Cheers.